# Tracking events for universal iOS app with Google Analytics

Tags: ios, google-analytics, ios-universal-app

I have an iOS app which is universal, for both iPhone and iPad. I want to use Google Analytics to track app usage.
I would like to track a certain event, like a button press - but I want to see if there is **a difference between event occurrence among iPhone and iPad users** of my app. Does anybody know how to do that with Google Analytics? Does it track the platform automatically?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can track it by put tracking call based on your event with device type like

```
id tracker = [[GAI sharedInstance] defaultTracker];
[tracker set:kGAIScreenName value:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"Your Event %@",([[UIDevice currentDevice] userInterfaceIdiom]==UIUserInterfaceIdiomPad?@"iPad":@"iPhone")]];
[tracker send:[[GAIDictionaryBuilder createAppView] build]];
```

Which ultimate outcome tracker as

```
Your Event iPhone //in case device is iPhone
//OR
Your Event iPad //in case device is iPad
```

Google Analytics gives you the device-os, and several other information. May be include Device type.

HTH, Enjoy Coding!!